# UIWebView first time allocation

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uiwebview

I have created a small test TabController app to test the memory usage of a `UIWebView`. On click of each tab presents a simple view controller which adds a `UIWebView` to the main view on `viewWillAppear`. The Webview loads a local test html file, which displays 1000 images.

On `viewWillDisappear`, I deallocate the WebView by removing it from the super view as I do not want multiple instances in memory. Before I deallocate the WebView I also call a method in the HTML implementation to destroy any objects contained in the browser window object.

What I have noticed is that when I initialize the `UIWebView` for the first time, it allocates around 600KB of memory. When I deallocate the WebView by switching tabs, I do not get that memory back.

When the next WebView is allocated and initialized after switching tabs, only around 20 KB of memory is allocated. When I click on the next tab, the current webview is deallocated and I get most of the 20KB back.

Is it just a matter of the operating system holding on to the dependent libraries it requires when rendering a `UIWebView`?

Here is my `viewWillAppear`/ `viewWillDisappear` methods:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[self view].frame];
     webView.delegate = self;
     [[self view] addSubview:webView];

     NSString *fileStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@""];
     NSMutableString* template = [NSMutableString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileStr] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

     NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
     NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

     NSData* d = [template dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     [webView loadData:d MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:baseURL];
     [webView release];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    webView.delegate = nil;
    [webView stopLoading];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"destroy();"];
    [webView removeFromSuperview];
}
```